# pushViewController debugging

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying (from my 3rd child in the heirachy) to load the root view with the following.  This does not work and I get the following error when the below code is run.

```
-[DetailViewController clickButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1161e00'
```

Code:

```
 MapViewController *dvController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        [dvController release];
        dvController = nil;
```

This exact same code works on other views, any idea how to debug this.

Comment: Not sure what you're end goal is. Do you want to send a message to a method on the RootViewController? Or, do you want to show the RootViewController (e.g. pop back to the rootViewController)?

Comment: Essentially I want to pop back to the rootViewController that has another view loaded within that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote to create the MapViewController and push it onto the view controller stack is correct.

The unrecognized selector error is telling you that you are sending are attempting to call a method (named clickButton:) that does not exist.

I would suspect a spelling error.  I take it that you most likely have a button defined that calls the code to create the new view.  The method should look like this:

```
-(void) clickButton: (id) sender {
    MapViewController *dvController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView"  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

I would check that you have the ":(id) sender" part.  I have made the mistake before of implementing a -(void) clickButton {}  method, but had the message actually sending a parameter as well.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo but still an error, see comment to post below.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have created the button programatically and set the target as clickButton, make sure the clickButton method is present
2. The clickButton method (according to the error) should take in an argument. So the definition of the method will be

   - (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender;
3. If you have mapped the IBAction to an event in IB, you can omit the :(id)sender part
4. To load the root view controller from any view in a navigation-based application, use

   [[self navigationController:popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Sorry as above I had a typo in the code.

If I take out all the code now and have a single NSLog that works and I can click the button till my hearts content.

The error I now get is...

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MapViewController 0x1172720> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key activityIndicator.'

Comment: That means you have an IBOutlet variable called activityIndicator but it is not mapped to a control in the nib file

Comment: Thanks but I don't have one in the code of the current view or the NIB.  In the MapView that I am trying to load this does and that has an IBOutlet as that works as I startAnimating that someplace else!???

Comment: Ok Strange,

I disconnected the activityIndicator in IB and reconnected it and got the following error instead...

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MapViewController 0x111ffa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key updatedLabel.'

However doing the same for this label results in the above :-(

Comment: In what class did you create the IBOutlet for the Activity Indicato, and Label?  If it was done in a subclass of MapViewController that you implemented, you will need to make sure that the MapViewController's subclass name is in IB, not the name of the superclass. is set to your subclass,  although without seeing the code, it's hard to say.

Comment: As Brad said, make sure all the object classes are set properly. This unbinding also happens if you change the name of the class after creating the bindings. Make sure the file's owner is an object of your viewcontroller and do the bindings again.

Comment: Cheers guys, I created a new nib and relinked it all. Must have been a stray!